# nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException:

Tags: java, spring

Iam calling another microservice from the application, when the data is more, Iam getting the below exception

```
nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException: 200 OK from GET https://ops-service.apps.com/api/v1/ops/list?page-size=150&page-offset=0; nested exception is org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144] with root cause
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144
    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.raiseLimitException(LimitedDataBufferList.java:99) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
```

I tried to resolve the above exception by trying as below, but did not worked and still getting the exception.
Included the below line in application.properties in both the micorservices.

```
spring.codec.max-in-memory-size=70MB
```

Any one has the solution for the above exception ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a custom bean like given below:

```
@Bean("webClient")
public WebClient customWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    return builder.baseUrl(host).build();
}
```

Alternatively,

```
@Bean("webClient")
    public WebClient customWebClient() {
        return WebClient
          .builder()
          .baseUrl(host)
          .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies
      .builder()
      .codecs(codecs -> codecs
            .defaultCodecs()
            .maxInMemorySize(size * 1024 * 1024))
        .build())
          .build();
}
```

Credits :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-databufferlimitexception